# Can't assign `std::str::Chars` to a variable of type `I: Iterator`

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to create a custom iterator over a string's characters, with the difference that it "splits" the string into two iterators. Which one is then used in its own `next()` depends on custom logic.

```rs
struct WrappingIter<I> {
    iter_1: I,
    iter_2: I,
    // ...
}

impl<I> WrappingIter<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    pub fn new(string: &str, start_idx: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter_1: string[start_idx..].chars(),
            iter_2: string[..start_idx].chars(),
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

That gives me this error (for both assignments):

```
 1  error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:38:25
    |
 29 |     impl<I> WrappingIter<I>
    |          - this type parameter
 ...
 38 |                 iter_1: string[start_idx..].chars(),
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `I`, found struct `Chars`
    |
    = note: expected type parameter `I`
                       found struct `Chars<'_>`
```

I can't tell why. [`std::str::Chars` implements the `Iterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#impl-Iterator-for-Chars%3C%27a%3E), so my logic was that I could directly assign it to `WrappingIter`'s members. Need I perhaps perform some sort of cast?

Comment: This can be addressed by [How to return concrete type from generic function?](/q/66207126/2189130) With a generic parameter, the *caller* gets to decide whar `I` is, not the body of the function. You can achieve what you want by returning `impl Iterator` (which *is* decided by the body of the function): [full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d554217cefd5636fba1a510dbb9c7533).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code can be roughly translated to "For *any* type `I` that implements the `Iterator` trait, define these methods in the following `impl` block for `WrappingIter<I>`" in English.

```rust
impl<I> WrappingIter<I> where I: Iterator { /* ... */ }
```

Notice that the type `I` can be *any* type that implements `Iterator`, but in the `new` method, an iterator of type `std::str::Chars` (which is not always equal to the type `I`) is assigned to it, which is why the code snippet fails to compile.

---

Here's a solution to make it compile by manually implementing the trait separately for each iterator type. For `std::str::Chars`, you have to annotate the lifetime explicitly, since the iterator is borrowed from a slice on the argument `string`. For an alternative solution without generics (and may be more practical), see @Finomnis's answer.

```rust
struct WrappingIter<I> {
    iter_1: I,
    iter_2: I,
}

impl<'i> WrappingIter<std::str::Chars<'i>> {
    pub fn new(string: &'i str, start_idx: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter_1: string[start_idx..].chars(),
            iter_2: string[start_idx..].chars(),
        }
    }
}

// for demo purpose, try with another Iterator type
impl WrappingIter<std::ops::Range<i64>> {
    pub fn new(range: std::ops::Range<i64>) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter_1: range.clone(),
            iter_2: range.clone(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rust's generics still trip me up. How can I fix that, then? Remove the generics entirely and make both `iter`s of type `Chars`?

Comment: How to fix it depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want `struct WrappingIter` to be able to hold any type that implements `Iterator`, or do you want it specifically for `std::str::Chars`? I may edit to update my answer accordingly with a solution.

Comment: This time, `Chars` will suffice, but I'd prefer a broader solution. If possible, there's no reason it shouldn't work on other kinds of iterators.

Comment: Your wrapping iterator example doesn't wrap. It just repeats ;)

Comment: While this does work, I think this is the wrong approach of working with generics. A generic should have bounds attached to it that specify what kind of generic it requires to perform its function. There are cases where you want to specify every single possible type for the generic, but I don't think this is one of them. See my answer for what I mean, if you do it correctly, you can implement your wrapping iterator for **every** type that implements `Iterator + Clone`.

Answer (score 2):

In your usecase, using a generic is the wrong approach.

Iterators are meant for the user of your library, to specify a type. In case of a wrapping iterator, why should the user of this iterator have to specify a type? The iterator will always be `Chars`.

What you **do** need, however, are lifetime annotations, because `Chars` borrow from your input string.

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

struct WrappingIter<'a> {
    iter_1: Chars<'a>,
    iter_2: Chars<'a>,
}

impl<'a> WrappingIter<'a> {
    pub fn new(string: &'a str, start_idx: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter_1: string[start_idx..].chars(),
            iter_2: string[..start_idx].chars(),
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for WrappingIter<'_> {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter_1.next().or_else(|| self.iter_2.next())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "abcdefgh";

    let s2 = WrappingIter::new(s, 3).collect::<String>();
    println!("{}", s2);
}
```

```
defghabc
```

---

However, if you want your `WrappingIter` to work for more than just `Chars`, then you do need the generic.

Again, generics are meant for the user of your function to be specified, and in this case the user will specify the type of iterator he passes into this function.

```rust
use std::iter::{Skip, Take};

struct WrappingIter<T> {
    iter_1: Skip<T>,
    iter_2: Take<T>,
}

impl<T> WrappingIter<T>
where
    T: Iterator + Clone,
{
    pub fn new(iter_in: T, start_idx: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter_1: iter_in.clone().skip(start_idx),
            iter_2: iter_in.take(start_idx),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for WrappingIter<T>
where
    T: Iterator,
{
    type Item = T::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter_1.next().or_else(|| self.iter_2.next())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "abcdefgh";

    let s2 = WrappingIter::new(s.chars(), 3).collect::<String>();
    println!("{}", s2);
}
```

```
defghabc
```

---

As a little excursion, you can then specify an iterator extension for all iterators:

```rust
use std::iter::{Skip, Take};

struct WrappingIter<T> {
    iter_1: Skip<T>,
    iter_2: Take<T>,
}

impl<T> WrappingIter<T>
where
    T: Iterator + Clone,
{
    pub fn new(iter_in: T, start_idx: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter_1: iter_in.clone().skip(start_idx),
            iter_2: iter_in.take(start_idx),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for WrappingIter<T>
where
    T: Iterator,
{
    type Item = T::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter_1.next().or_else(|| self.iter_2.next())
    }
}

trait IteratorWrapExt
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    fn wrap(self, start_idx: usize) -> WrappingIter<Self>;
}

impl<T> IteratorWrapExt for T
where
    T: Iterator + Clone,
{
    fn wrap(self, start_idx: usize) -> WrappingIter<Self> {
        WrappingIter::new(self, start_idx)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "abcdefgh";

    let s2 = s.chars().wrap(3).collect::<String>();
    println!("{}", s2);

    let v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let v2 = v.iter().wrap(3).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", v2);

    // It even works with ranges
    let r = (10..15).wrap(2).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

```
defghabc
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[12, 13, 14, 10, 11]
```

---

Another quick info:

Wrapping is almost free for every iterator that can jump without cost (like ranges or array iters), but **not** for strings. Strings have variably-sized elements (a UTF-8 char can have 1 to 4 bytes), and so wrapping requires iterating over the wrapped elements twice.